# Errors when writing/reading a file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, std, ifstream, ofstream

I have 2 functions working with the same file. The first function reads from a file:

```
myRepositoryPointCloud::point3d myRepositoryPointCloud::Reading(int i, int j, int k)
{
  ifstream rf("C:\\PointCloud.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);
  if (!rf) {
      cout << "Cannot open file!" << endl;
  }

  point3d resultPt;
  rf.seekg((i * GetCntPointY() * GetCntPointZ() + j * GetCntPointZ() + k) * sizeof(point3d));

  rf.read((char *)&resultPt, sizeof(point3d));

  rf.close();
  if (!rf.good()) {
      cout << "Error occurred at reading time!" << endl;
  }
  return resultPt;
}
```

The secnd function write in the same file:

```
void myRepositoryPointCloud::Writing(int i, int j, int k, point3d & APoint)
{
  ofstream wf("C:\\PointCloud.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);

  if (!wf) {
      cout << "Cannot open file!" << endl;
  }

  wf.seekp((i * GetCntPointY() * GetCntPointZ() + j * GetCntPointZ() + k) * sizeof(point3d));

  wf.write((char *)&APoint, sizeof(point3d));

  wf.close();
  if (!wf.good()) {
      cout << "Error occurred at writing time!" << endl;
  }
}
```

They are both called in a loop:

```
      point3d CurrentPoint;

      for (int i = 0; i < EndPoint.i - StartPoint.i; i++)
        {
          for (int j = 0; j < EndPoint.j - StartPoint.j; j++)
            {
              for (int k = 0; k < EndPoint.k - StartPoint.k; k++)
                {
                  CurrentPoint = FPointCloud->Reading(i, j, k);

                  if (!CurrentPoint.deleted) 
                  {
                    Sphere->CalcIntersectSphereToPoint(&CurrentPoint);                    

                    if (CurrentPoint.deleted || CurrentPoint.visible)
                    {
                       FPointCloud->Writing(i, j, k, &CurrentPoint);
                    }
                  }
            }
        }
    }
```

First function reading variable value from file, then program do some things with them, and then this variable value write to file second function at the same position i, j, k. Problem occured at the second step of loop. The reading function return "Error occurred at reading time!". Without calling in loop second function Writing - all ok. Maybe I'm not freeing some resources in the second function?

Comment: Was it intentional, you're opening you reader with `ios::out|ios::binary` ? Just curious. Also, I'm not convinced the repeated open/close operations on that file with your chosen mode flags is doing what you desire. I suggest you debug your program and do a hexdump or xxd of the file after each invoke of `Writing`. You may be surprised.

Comment: These flags `ios::out|ios::binary` were chosen in the example. Now I corrected in the reader for `ios::in` - it did not help.

Comment: is it possible that the position is incorrect? I bet the first one is 0,0,0 so the position is correct. Maybe the second one seeks to the wrong place?

Comment: by the way, opening and closing the file twice for every point will make your program slow

Comment: I know about slow working this code. This code just demonstrate and draws attention on problem. In working code I'm read/write the array of points at once.

Comment: How did you call the function in loop? Please  provide  a minimal, reproducible sample.